# iTunes Connect & App Store: can you remove a "Ready for Sale" version until replaced with a new one?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, submission

I have the following question and I don't find it in the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34) document: if I have an app in the "Ready for Sale" status, I know I can remove it from sale by deselecting territories, and put it back on sale again by selecting the territories. But, could I remove an app from sale, submit a new version, and put back on sale this new version once approved? Or you are only allowed to submit new versions of an app if it is on sale?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what I wanted:

> You can add a new version of an app when the current version’s status is “Ready for Sale” or Developer Removed From Sale. The new app version goes through the same review process as the first version.